# Перенос строк html

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

Есть textarea, в который вводится текст с переносами. Затем, этот текст добавляется в div, но там уже он отображается без переносов... В чем проблема?)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: html по умолчанию нигде никогда не отображает переносы, если вы до сих пор этого почему-то не заметили)

Answer (score 0):

Решается white-space: pre-line;